# Random effects model with individual means

Tags: time-series, random-effects-model

I am trying to run a panel data model, where my DV is a PCA component, and the main IV is time-invariant (shares of ethnic group in total population). 
Therefore, I could not use the fixed effect model, even if all of the tests told me to use it. 
Anyways, I with the recommendation of my prof. I decided to use a RE model with individual means (control variables). 
The results are following:

```
Random-effects GLS regression                   Number of obs      =       400
Group variable: provnum                         Number of groups   =        80

R-sq:  within  = 0.0852                         Obs per group: min =         5
       between = 0.9999                                        avg =       5.0
       overall = 0.9961                                        max =         5

                                                Wald chi2(12)      =  1.06e+06
corr(u_i, X)   = 0 (assumed)                    Prob > chi2        =    0.0000

                               (Std. Err. adjusted for 80 clusters in provnum)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
     PubInst |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         shK |  -.0178875    .008945    -2.00   0.046    -.0354194   -.0003557
      shAgri |  -.8904352   2.083263    -0.43   0.669    -4.973556    3.192685
       shInd |  -1.862738   1.464498    -1.27   0.203    -4.733102    1.007626
      shServ |   -1.86017   1.616578    -1.15   0.250    -5.028604    1.308265
          UR |  -.5932532   .3282967    -1.81   0.071    -1.236703    .0501966
        Cexp |   -.543176   .9847452    -0.55   0.581    -2.473241    1.386889
    mPubInst |   .9951743   .0020266   491.05   0.000     .9912022    .9991464
     mshAgri |  -.9446586   .5531663    -1.71   0.088    -2.028845    .1395273
      mshInd |   .0066544   .9026024     0.01   0.994    -1.762414    1.775723
     mshServ |          0  (omitted)
         mUR |   .5658647   .3269263     1.73   0.083    -.0748991    1.206629
       mCexp |   .5274118   1.023078     0.52   0.606    -1.477785    2.532608
    mPubInst |          0  (omitted)
     yearnum |   .0162697   .0304386     0.53   0.593    -.0433888    .0759282
       _cons |   1.605548   1.506115     1.07   0.286    -1.346384     4.55748
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |          0
     sigma_e |  .16244148
         rho |          0   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
```

I am worried, because R-sq are very high, and rho is 0. This is my first research using econometrics, so I apologize if this is a simple issue.